# How to pass a Mutable list from fragment to another fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm new to Kotlin and Fragments, actually in my App i have two fragments, Fragment1 and Fragment2

In the first fragment i have a method which get data from some editTexts and add them to a MutableList then in my Fragment2 i have a ListView in which i would be able to show that MutableList...

But how can i pass the MutableList from Fragment1 to Fragment2?

Here is my Fragment1 code:

```
 private var listArticoli: MutableList<Articolo>? = null
private fun addBarcode(barcode: String, qta: String) {
    if (barcode.isEmpty()) {
        txtBarcode.requestFocus()
        return;
    }

    listArticoli?.add(Articolo(barcode, qta.toInt()))

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    txtBarcode = view.findViewById(R.id.txtBarcode)

    listArticoli = mutableListOf()


    btnArticoli.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment) // button on click of which i navigate to Fragment2
    }
}
```

Fragment2 code:

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var listView: ListView

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView)

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnIndietro).setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `safeargs` to pass the data between fragments,check out the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data) for more info

Answer (score 0):

To access Mutable list in both the fragments,you can create ViewModel which consists of MutableLiveDate of you required data type.Then expose MutableLiveData from viewmodel.So use the same ViewModel in both the fragments by setting data from one fragment1 and by observing data from fragment2.

**SampleViewModel.kt**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class SampleViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var mutableLiveData:MutableLiveData<MutableList<Articolo> = MutableLiveData()
 }
```

**Fragment1.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle 
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class Fragment1 : Fragment() {

private lateinit var viewModel: SampleViewModel
var arrayList: ArrayList<Articolo> = ArrayList()

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
): View? {
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SampleViewModel::class.java)
    //TODO: Add data to arraylist
    viewModel.mutableLiveData.value = arrayList

}
```

}

**Fragment2.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class Fragment2 : Fragment() {

private lateinit var viewModel: SampleViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
): View? {

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SampleViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.mutableLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
      //TODO:Can do you requirements here
    })

}
```

}

Comment: Hi Tarun, could you make an example of how can i use MutableLiveData with an Array of my Articolo object?

Comment: Hi @KasperJuner As requested provided example.Please check if it is useful

Answer (score 0):

1.Share the viewmodel with their common parent activity

2.FragmentResultListener from fragment(after 1.3.0-alpha04)